# Test for occurrences of pairs from samples with different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, nonparametric

I have two collections of data, A and B, each containing a large number of 10-digit binary strings. For instance, an element of A could be a=1011001111, and an element of B could be b=1001010000. I cannot assume that ones and zeroes occur with equal relative frequency in A and B.

I'm looking for a way to test whether '11'-pairs occur more frequently compared to a null hypothesis in A than in B. In other words, given null hypotheses where strings in A and B are random ten-digit strings with different P(1|A) and P(1|B), is the frequency of 11's more unlikely in A than in B?

The approach I have in mind is: For each string, consider all its possible permutations. Given that, compute the t-statistic for the number of 11-pairs in the string. Then use a non-parametric test like Mann-Whitney to test if t-values in A are larger than t-values in B.

Is this a sensible approach or is there another way I should go about testing this?

Comment: how to count "11" pair when 10 digit number is 1111111111? count as 5, 9, or others?

Comment: I would count that as 9

Comment: That seems to be the right idea, but it could be daunting to consider all possible permutations for all strings in your data.  Perhaps a better approach would be to simulate the permutations yourself and count the occurrences of 11 in the actual and permuted data.

Comment: It's not that daunting is it? For a given number of ones and zeroes in a string, there fewer than 2^10 permutations. You only need to go over each of those once and compute the probability distribution for pairs, and after that you can just iterate over the strings and look up the corresponding distribution?